# Finding quadrupole moment

Tags: electrostatics, multipole-expansion

The potential of a $2^n$ pole can be found by,

$$
\varphi_n =\frac{p^{(n)}}{4\pi\epsilon_0 n!}\frac{\partial^{'n}}{\partial l_n \partial l_{n-1} ... \partial l_1} \bigg(\frac{1}{r} \bigg)
$$

where

$$
p^{(n)} = n ! q \Delta l_n \Delta l_{n-1} ... \Delta l_1
$$

is the multipole moment. $\Delta l_n$ is the distance between the charges of $n$-dipole.

If I have a quadrupole such that the dipoles are perpendicular to each other and their midpoints coincide, i.e. a '+' like structure, then

$\Delta l_2 = 0$

since the midpoints coincide. That means the potential of the quadrupole is zero.

Is this reasoning correct?